# PHP invoice PDF - Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php

I needed to create an invoice using PHP. Initially, I used FPDF to craft my own invoice. While it worked, it didn't produce the desired results.

Then, I stumbled upon this GitHub Project: [artkonekt/pdf-invoice](https://github.com/artkonekt/pdf-invoice)

It was exactly what I needed! The code is clean, and the resulting invoice is both elegant and customizable.

However, I encountered a setback when generating an invoice. An error message popped up:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 119486103 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/*********/vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1366

To address this, I resorted to using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`. Nevertheless, I believe this solution may not be optimal. Furthermore, the generation process is quite time-consuming.

Do you happen to know of a more effective approach to speed things up? I'm also open to exploring alternative GitHub projects if you have any recommendations.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

This is the code that is generating the invoice :

```
/* Header settings */
        $invoice->setLogo(__DIR__ . "/../assets/img/logo-couleur.png");   //logo image path
        $invoice->setColor("#ff3b44");      // pdf color scheme
        $invoice->setType("Facture");    // Invoice Type
        $invoice->setNumberFormat(",", " ", "right", true, false);
        $invoice->setReference($this->FactureId);   // Reference
        $invoice->setDate(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($this->Date)));   //Billing Date
        $invoice->setFrom(array("CORP1", "38 Blv Carnot, ", "Bureau 3", "Lille , 59000"));

        //setting client information
        if (var_check($user->BillingAdress)) {
            if (var_check($user->BillingAdress->Ligne2)) {
                $invoice->setTo(
                    array(
                        $user->BillingAdress->Denomination,
                        $user->BillingAdress->Ligne1,
                        $user->BillingAdress->Ligne2,
                        $user->BillingAdress->Ville . ', ' . $user->BillingAdress->CodePostal,
                        "Code client : " . $user->UserId
                    )
                );
            } else {
                $invoice->setTo(
                    array(
                        $user->BillingAdress->Denomination,
                        $user->BillingAdress->Ligne1,
                        $user->BillingAdress->Ville . ', ' . $user->BillingAdress->CodePostal,
                        "Code client : " . $user->UserId
                    )
                );
            }
        } else {
            if (var_check($user->ShippingAdress->Ligne2)) {
                $invoice->setTo(
                    array(
                        $user->NameDisplayed,
                        $user->ShippingAdress->Ligne1,
                        $user->ShippingAdress->Ligne2,
                        $user->ShippingAdress->Ville . ', ' . $user->ShippingAdress->CodePostal,
                        "Code client : " . $user->UserId
                    )
                );
            } else {
                $invoice->setTo(
                    array(
                        $user->NameDisplayed,
                        $user->ShippingAdress->Ligne1,
                        $user->ShippingAdress->Ville . ', ' . $user->ShippingAdress->CodePostal,
                        "Code client : " . $user->UserId
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        $invoice->flipflop(); //client information on the left

        $totalHT = 0;
        $totalTTC = 0;
        foreach ($this->LignesFacture as $ligne) {
            $totalHT = $totalHT + $ligne->PrixHT;
            $totalTTC = $totalTTC + $ligne->PrixTTC;
            $invoice->addItem($ligne->Description, (var_check($ligne->Detail) ? $ligne->Detail : false), false, false, $ligne->PrixHT/100, false, $ligne->PrixTTC/100);
        }

        $invoice->addTotal("Total HT", $totalHT/100);
        $invoice->addTotal("TVA 20%", ($totalTTC - $totalHT)/100);
        $invoice->addTotal("Total TTC", $totalTTC/100, true);

        if (var_check($payingDate)) {
            $invoice->addBadge("Payé le " . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($payingDate)), "#198754");
        }

        $invoice->addParagraph("Numéro de commande : " . $this->CommandeId);

        $invoice->addParagraph("Je vous ai envoyé cette facture le " . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($this->Date)) . ". Celle-ci doit être réglée sous 30 jour(s) à compter de cette date. Passé ce délai, une pénalité de retard de 10 % sera appliquée, ainsi qu'une indemnité forfaitaire de 40€ due au titre des frais de recouvrement. Pas d'escompte pour règlement anticipé.");

        $invoice->setFooternote("CORP1 SAS | SIRET 91076923100036 | TVA FR65910769231");

        $invoice->changeLanguageTerm('price', 'Prix HT');
        $invoice->changeLanguageTerm('total', 'Prix TTC');
        $invoice->changeLanguageTerm('number', 'Facture n°');
        $invoice->changeLanguageTerm('date', 'Date');
        $invoice->changeLanguageTerm('product', 'Désignation');


        $invoice->render(__DIR__ . '/../assets/factures/' . $user->UserId . $this->FactureId . '.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: It is still using fpdf when I read the error message. Please provide code and data to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Checking out the error it seems to have to do with the way FPDF renders a PNG image. Try to skip the `setLogo()` and see if that helps. It might be that FPDF cannot cope with your PNG image. Is it especially big, or otherwise abnormal?

Comment: This is it ! My logo size 532 ko. I remove the setLogo() and no problem !
I will try using a smaller image now.

Comment: The _file size_ of your logo image isn't so much what is relevant here to begin with, more likely you're having this problem due to its pixel dimensions. Even if a, say, 3000 * 3000 pixel image _compressed_ to a nice little file size due to its actual content - _rendering_ that image will still require 3000 * 3000 * 3 bytes (RGB) - or even * 4 bytes, when the library is able to handle alpha transparency (RGBA) - of memory.

Comment: Oh you're right. My image was 11863 × 4045...
I resize it to 700x250 and it works even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's for your help !

So the problem was that my logo was to big (over 500ko, 11863 × 4045 px). I resize it to 700x250px, so now it's 52Ko and it works !

It's fast and I do not need `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` anymore !

Thank's again and I hope it can now help someone else ;)

Comment: Yes, the logo was too big, but more important, did you understand how it was found out that the image was the problem? Knowing how to debug code can help you in the future with any error you can encounter.

Comment: FYK, settting `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` is not the answer.